# Path contains mininal heavy weight from s to t

Tags: algorithm, breadth-first-search, dijkstra

I need to write an algorithm that find a path from s to t by the following condition:
we compare bewteen each heaviest edge of each path and choose the path with the lightest edge among the heaviest edges

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what seems to be going wrong? This seems like a straightforward, minor modification of Dijkstra's algorithm.